# How to upload a range of data inside "list" results in invalid values

Tags: c#, google-api, google-sheets-api, google-api-dotnet-client

I am having a problem to upload a list data from C# to google sheets.

First trial I tried to follow this code. And it was worked.

```
static void CreateEntry() { 
var range = $"{sheet}!A:F";
var valueRange = new ValueRange();

var oblist = new List<object>() { "Hello!", "This", "was", "insertd", "via", "C#" };
valueRange.Values = new List<IList<object>> { oblist };

var appendRequest = service.Spreadsheets.Values.Append(valueRange, SpreadsheetId, range);
appendRequest.ValueInputOption = SpreadsheetsResource.ValuesResource.AppendRequest.ValueInputOptionEnum.USERENTERED;
var appendReponse = appendRequest.Execute();
}
```

Then I want to change the "Hello!", "This", "was", "insertd", "via", "C#" with my data on the list that has been made.

```
//Input Data
        var valueRange = new ValueRange();

        var oblist = new List<object>() { list1 };

        valueRange.Values = new List<IList<object>> { oblist };

        var appendRequest = service.Spreadsheets.Values.Append(valueRange, spreadsheetId, range);
        appendRequest.ValueInputOption = SpreadsheetsResource.ValuesResource.AppendRequest.ValueInputOptionEnum.USERENTERED;
        var appendResponse = appendRequest.Execute();
```

But I get this error report.

```
Google.GoogleApiException: 'Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError
```

Error Report

[image]

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: what is `list1` ?

Comment: I gather sensor data from serialPort, then collect it into the list1. @CallumMorrisson

Comment: yeah but what type is it, ie. `List<string>`.

Comment: actually whatever type it is, you're inserting it as the first element in a list that expects values, that will never work. if `list1` is a list of value types, then change your code to `valueRange.Values = new List<IList<object>> { list1 };`, otherwise figure out how to get the contents of `list1` into `oblist` as individual values.

Comment: the type is double. I have tried your suggestion but I get the CS1950 and CS1503 error code @CallumMorrisson

Comment: what did you try?

Comment: What length is your list?

Comment: about 100 sample per second @RafaGuillermo